# Can I create a date object where the year is non applicable?

Tags: java

I am trying to create a date object that doesn't have a year as that wouldn't be applicable (it represents a time of the year rather than a specific year).

I would like to use the actual Date class if possible, since my framework has an automatic HTTP binding to this.

There isn't a constructor to do this.

Comment: What do you mean by "time of the year"?

Comment: What do you mean by "date without year" ? You can assum that date is irrelevant and by default use 1900 year...

Comment: @Vash 1900 is not a good choice, because it's not a leap year :)

Comment: I hope you are not planning to calculate number of days between two such dates or anything similar, because without the year you won't know how many days does February have.

Answer (score 3):

It's not clear what you mean by "an automatic HTTP binding" - in what context? How is this value going to be communicated?

You could create a `Date` using some arbitrary year - 2012 would be good for example, as that will support February 29th. However, whatever *uses* the data on the other end will need to know to ignore the year part. (Of course, you should be using `Calendar` to create the year in the first place, given that the `Date` constructors taking year/month/day etc are deprecated.)

Whatever you do, a `Date` represents an instant in time - there's no concept of a `Date` without a year any more than there is a `Date` without an hour. It's an instant, that's all. It doesn't have an associated time zone, or calendar, or format string, or any concept of which bits are useful. The code which uses it will need to take care of that.

Personally I'd recommend using [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) for all date/time work in Java. It doesn't actually have a MonthDay type as far as I can see (which is what you want) but you could use a `LocalDate` and ignore the year. Or you could implement `ReadablePartial` yourself, but that would be rather more work :)

Comment: I guess I gave same answer before you :) , your answer is absolutely better but.. :)

Comment: @org.life.java but he is Jon Skeet.. :D

Comment: @Lipis His answer is far better , and yes JS factor works :) , @Jon I hope you don't mind

Comment: @org.life.java: Well, I don't really think our answers *are* the same... you talk about "overriding" a year field, but that doesn't really make much sense. There's a difference between "use an arbitrary value in the constructor" and "ignore".

Comment: my answer is as simple as `You can ignore year field in this case.` . and I accept your answer is far better

Answer (score 3):

You could also simply extend the `Date` class with one constructor with two parameters for `month` and `day`, which you can use it as you would use a `Date` in your framework.

Here is an example that will give you a `Date` of the year 2012, which includes the February 29th:

```
public class MyDate extends Date {
    static private final long START = 1325286000000L; // Dec 31st, 2011
    static private final long ONE_DAY = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
    static private final int[] DAYS = {0, 31, 60, 91, 121, 152, 182, 213, 244, 274, 305, 335};

    public MyDate(int month, int day) {
        super(START + (DAYS[month - 1] + day) * ONE_DAY);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can ignore year field in this case. as you want to use `Date` only, by default if you don;t override it would hold current year

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you really don't care about any date logic or validation, just do this:

```
public class YearlessDate{
    private int month;
    private int day;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are libraries that implement *partial dates*, which do exactly what you want. For example, joda's [Partial](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/key_partial.html).

Answer (score 1):

You could also have a look at the ThreeTen project:

http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/threeten/index.php?title=ThreeTen

It provides a MonthDay class:

- http://threeten.sourceforge.net/apidocs/javax/time/calendar/MonthDay.html
- http://threeten.sourceforge.net/apidocs/

ThreeTen is the reference implementation of the JSR 310: Date and Time API

http://jcp.org/en/jsr/summary?id=310

and is currently planned to be included in Java SE 8:

http://jcp.org/en/jsr/proposalDetails?id=337#3